# Interpolating missing pixels from land cover classification map

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, interpolation, land-classification

On Google Earth Engine, I created a classified land cover map based on a composite of images (spanning 2 years). It's a time series study so increasing the range of images (i.e. increasing to more than 2 years) would be detrimental.

The missing pixels are very minimal only about 3-5% of my study area but they're a hindrance to simulation modeling (my end goal).

I understand that QGIS has "Fill NoData cells" in its Processing Toolbox which works to an extent but also creates pixels outside of my study area. I only want to fill in the "holes" caused by the missing pixels.

**Is there another way to interpolate the missing pixels? Using GEE or QGIS?** and is interpolating these missing pixels generally acceptable?

Comment: for QGIS see: https://spatialthoughts.com/2020/06/17/fix-nodata-values/

Comment: Hi! Yes, I have seen that (and I've mentioned that in my 3rd paragraph). 

I'd like to know though if it's a generally acceptable practice to do so.

Comment: Are you trying to interpolate between imagery in your time-series or based on adjacent pixels?

Comment: Hi! Just based on adjacent pixels. (context: all of the images in my time-series range seem to have missing pixels in a similar area).

I'm thinking the FillNoData cells tools is acceptable? It uses IDW interpolation.